# ASP.net MVC create related object using partials

Tags: asp.net-mvc, partial

I am relatively new to ASP and MVC but have got on ok so far.  I am using the DB first approach and have my DB tables all setup (it is an existing DB cleaned up with FKs etc).

I have a route of FKs:

```
Contact
    - LettingContact
         - Landlord          
         - Tenant
```

I would like to be able to use partials to display the data e.g. /Contact/_Create will hold the Contact info i.e. Title, Forename, Surname and will be used both by /Contact/Create and /Tenant/Create.  I managed to get it working not using the partials and just using the field on the Tenant/Create html form and showing the relevant data from the models.  To the Tenant/Create in the controller i did the following (doing the following stopped me getting null exceptions in the partial)

```
Tenant tenant = new Tenant();
LettingsContact lettingsContact = new LettingsContact();
Contact contact = new Contact();
tenant.LettingsContact = letContact;
tenant.LettingsContact.Contact = contact;
return View(tenant)
```

Now the View is

```
//using Html.BeginForm etc

@{
   Html.RenderPartial("../Contact/_Create", Model.LettingsContact.Contact);
   Html.RenderPartial("_Create", Model);
}


<input type="submit" value="create">

//rest of html
```

Now when I click the submit button it goes to my /Tenant/Create post event.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Tenant  tenant)
{
     if (ModelState.IsValue)
     {
         tenant.ContactID = Guid.NewGuid();
         tenant.LettingsContact.Contact.ContactID = tenant.ContactID;
         db.Tenants.AddObject(tenant);
         db.SaveChanges();
         return RedirectToAction("Index");             
     }
}
```

However the line which reads `tenant.LettingContact.Contact.ContactID` crashes will a NullReferenceException to the LettingsContact is null.  Any reason why the partials are not maintaining the Models?

Also if there is a better way of doing this please let me know as this is still very new to me.

The reason I want to use partials is that it will enable me to reuse the forms in jQuery modal forms etc.

Comment: Is more information required?  Thanks

Comment: It confuses between tenant argument and tenant property.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a form to post back information that you don't want displayed on the page you should use a hidden field. Have a look at `Html.Hidden()` and `Html.HiddenFor()`.

Hidden on msdn: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.inputextensions.hidden.aspx

HiddenFor on msdn: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.inputextensions.hiddenfor.aspx

Comment: Thanks, i found another (less elegant)  way but will try this for next time :)